# Checking if a binary vector lies in the affine span of given binary vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, computational-geometry

Let $x_1, \ldots,x_N \in \{0,1\}^D$ be $N$ binary vectors, assumed affinely independent (in the field of reals). Is there an efficient algorithm for determining whether a new binary vector $x_{N+1}$ is in the $\mathbb{R}$-affine span of $x_1,\ldots,x_N$?

By "efficient" I mean faster than having to test linear independence, i.e., something that exploits the fact that the vectors are binary.

Comment: Linear algebra over $\Bbb F_2$ or over another field?

Comment: No, over the field of real numbers. Just edited to make the question more clear.